# How to find index of item in contract mapping

Tags: mapping, ethereum, contract

I have a mapping defined in my ethereum contract as follows

```
mapping (string => string) client;
```

I have a function that is trying to add clients to this mapping but before i add i wanna check if item already exists. Is there a way i can get index of an item in that either by a out of the box method which is like "get me the index of item in this mapping if value is this" or maybe iterate through the mapping inside the contract

```
function AddClient(string clientName) {

}
```

Comment: I accomplished this by keeping a parallel array of the key names. Then you can use a for loop to get the index for a key and a simple return to get the mapping element at the index, e.g., myMappingElements[myKeyElements[i]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish it but you have to manage things at a lower level because there is no out-of-the-box way to interrogate the mapping for that information. Have a look at this piece that describes some basic storage patterns. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity

Hope it helps.